# How to install jcdk 2.2.1 in Eclipse [Version: Kepler Service Release 2]?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, smartcard, javacard

I want to install jcdk 2.2.1 in Eclipse, but it only accept jcdk 2.2.2! as you see in the below I have *converter.jar is not compatible* error.
How I can solve this problem? thank you.

**Update: I try to install JCDK 2.2.1 with jcde 0.1 or 0.2 installed on Eclipse!but nothing change. and in both, Eclipse require directory of JCDK 2.2.2**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set eclipse with **java kit 2.2.2** then I close eclipse window and replace the contents of **java kit 2.2.2** with contents if **java kit 2.2.1** and the problem solved.

Comment: Sounds like a hack but if it works it works I suppose. If the .jar is too incompatible you may run into runtime errors though. Check if you can post again, I've voted up the most reasonable questions.

Comment: thank you very very much dear owlstead :) yes I can. I promise that  I'll be ask concise question ;)

Answer (score -1):

[java card kit 2.2.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#java_card_kit-2.2.2-oth-JPR) file is good, you have to :

1. unzip the file you downloaded.
2. open the folder named java card kit 2.2.2
3. unzip the folder that finishes with "windows-do" or "linux-do" (depends of what you downloaded/needed).
4. Finally, come back to eclipse, and browse to that last folder you unzipped.